# Small value approximation to double series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, approximation-theory

I have this function expressed as a series:

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2} -\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n\pi}\exp(-n^2\pi^2t)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

It comes from the Fourier series expansion of a function of two variables $(t, x)$ but I wanted to see the dependence for a single $x$ and small $t$.

I was about to proceed by saying *"Since $t\ll1$ it follows that $\exp(-n^2\pi^2t)\approx1-n^2\pi^2t$"*, because for sufficiently small $t$ the higher order terms should vanish.

The problem is of course that $n$ is not bounded and consequently my approach doesn't work because no matter how small $t$ is, there will always be an $n$ that makes my linear approximation of the exponential wrong.

So, is there a way to correctly express the small $t$ approximation to $f(t)$ or do I necessarily have to take all the terms?

I thought that maybe the sign alternation in the $\sin(n\pi/2)$ can help some approximation be convergent, in the way normal convergence criteria are easier to evaluate with alternating signs.

Note that I'm an aspiring physicist, so I apologize for any mistakes made within the context of rigorous mathematical analysis. Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you're solving the heat equation? It might be useful to include this as well as the the boundary conditions.

Comment: Something like that. It comes from the expression for the (nondimensionalized) velocity of a simple shear flow. I am considering the middle point, exactly. But the whole expression is $$\bar{u}=(1-\bar{y})-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n\pi}\exp(-n^2\pi^2\bar{t})\sin(n\pi\bar{y})$$ In this case the bar means they're nondimensionalized ($\bar{y}$ ranges from 0 to 1 and $\bar{t}$ is a non-negative real number). The boundary conditions are $\bar{u}(0)=1$ and $\bar{u}(1)=0$.

Comment: Should the sin term have t?

Comment: @martycohen in this case no, the solution only has the time in the exponential part. It probably came from a heat equation-type Fourier solution where the modes decay exponentially at a rate proportional to their frequency.

Comment: Then the sin terms are zero for even n and $\pm 1$ for odd n.

Comment: Yes, for that particular point ($\bar{y}=1/2$), they are exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) provides a way to handle small $t$ well. Let $y>0$ and $$S(x,y)=x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n\pi}e^{-(n\pi y)^2}\sin n\pi x,$$ so that $f(t)=1-S(1/2,\sqrt{t})$. Then the formula tells $S(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}s(x,y,n)$, where $$s(x,y,\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(\pi ty)^2-2\pi i\omega t}\frac{\sin\pi tx}{\pi t}\,dt$$ can be evaluated using "$\partial/\partial x$ trick" and known $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2-zt}\,dt=e^{z^2/4}\sqrt\pi$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ (!): $$s_x(x,y,\omega)=\frac{1}{2y\sqrt\pi}\left(e^{-\left(\frac{\omega}{y}+\frac{x}{2y}\right)^2}+e^{-\left(\frac{\omega}{y}-\frac{x}{2y}\right)^2}\right),$$ so that integration w.r.t. $x$, with noting that $s(0,y,\omega)=0$ clearly, gives $$s(x,y,\omega)=\frac12\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\omega}{y}+\frac{x}{2y}\right)-\frac12\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\omega}{y}-\frac{x}{2y}\right).$$  Thus, if $0<x<1$, then $\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}S(x,y)=1$, and the "error" is [$\mathcal{O}(e^{-(x/2y)^2}y/x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion), **very** small.

Comment: I mean... It's technically correct but I could have obtained $f(y, 0)=0$ just from the initial condition, or by directly substituing $t=0$ (the series just turns into a multiple of Euler's famous sum for $\pi / 4$ when considering the nonzero values of the sine. I was hoping more for an expression that worked for small but nonzero values of $t$...

Comment: Still, this gives me some ideas about what I could try in order to obtain such an expression. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I should have put more emphasis on the "error" term. When $t$ is small (but positive), $f(t)$ is *very, very* close to $0$; it tends to $0$ quicker than $t^a$ for arbitrarily large $a$. (Also, the alternative representation obtained is *exact*, not just an approximation... but this is less important for the question.)

Comment: Ohh! I see now. I thought there was a way to express it as a polynomial in $t$, I guess I was wrong. One last concern... Is $S(x,y)$ strictly less than 1 for finite $t$? Is there a way to show something like that?

Comment: Yes, for $0<x<1$ it is easy to see from the result rewritten as $$1-S(x,y)=\operatorname{erfc}\frac{x}{2y}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\operatorname{erfc}\frac{2n-x}{2y}-\operatorname{erfc}\frac{2n+x}{2y}\right)$$ (just regroup the terms in pairs differently).